# Twig {% if object.getPermisisons.check(app.user) %}

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

I am learning to extend twig ([twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html)).

I want to check if the current user exists in a set of users and groups (**permissions** forms a many-to-one relationship with a **user** entity and a **groups** entity).

Currently the twig function check() is an extension in my bundle, iterating through **permissions** for each **user** and users in each **groups**, comparing the current user, and returning true or false.

I know I can pass in two parameters to the twig function: `check(app.user, object.getPermissions)`, my question is can I call the function on the first param: `object.getPermissions.check(app.user)`?

From what I have read, it seems like it only recognizes *is*'s and *get*'s, but I wanted to reach out to the community and see what is possible.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`object.getPermissions.check(app.user)` means that whatever the method `getPermissions()` returns the code will expect the returned value to have a method `check()`.

Two solutions to your problem (one that is close to what you want and another that is a bit cleaner):

- Create a [Twig filter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html) to have a syntax such as `object.getPermissions|check(app.user)` however I am personally not fan of it.
- Create a method on the object that does exactly what you are expecting. A self-explanatory example would be a method name like `hasViewAccess($user)` or `hasCreateAccess($user)` so you could easily do `{% if object.hasCreateAccess(app.user) %}`.

If you need the service container then you could create a Twig filter `hasCreateAccess` that you call against the object. It would look like this `{% if object|hasCreateAccess(app.user) %}`. It is definitely the most flexible solution.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. I will go and try it out!